# gridExtra tableGrob error of wrong sign when using grid.draw()

Tags: r, viewport, gridextra

The following code

```
xta=t(rnorm(37,mean=400,sd=50))
xtb=tableGrob(xta,show.rownames=F,show.colnames=F,gpar.corefill=gpar(fill='white',col='black'),show.vlines=T,show.hlines=T)
grid.draw(xtb)
```

gives me an error of

```
Error in seq.default(2, ncol, 1) : wrong sign in 'by' argument
```

`grid.table(t(xta))`

### Edit (mnel)

This can be traced to the `show.hline` argument`

```
 grid.table(xta, show.hline = TRUE)
```

gives

> Error in seq.default(2, ncol, 1) : wrong sign in 'by' argument

while the default

```
grid.table(xta)
```

works well.

the same issue arises when you pass `d` as a `data.frame`, (as function requires)

```
xtdf <- as.data.frame(xta)

grid.table(xtdf, show.hline = TRUE)

## Error in seq.default(2, nrow, 1) : wrong sign in 'by' argument
##  grid.table(xtdf) 
## works as expected
```

Comment: This has absolutly nothing to do with `ggplot2`. it is an issue with `grid.table`. and the `show.hlines=TRUE` argument. `grid.table(xta,show.hlines=FALSE)` works, `grid.table(xta,show.hlines=TRUE)` does not. (replicated with `as.data.frame(xta)` )

Comment: thanks @mnel, that actually answers the question. Overzealous coding on my part.

Comment: that's an unfortunate bug in tableGrob; the calculation to draw the separator lines is obviously too fragile